# Is it possible to make a mounted SMB share behave as a system directory?

Tags: smb, freenas

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I am not really sure the correct terminology for what I am asking (which is also making searching for an answer kid of tricky).

Basically, I have a TrueNas box on the network, with several SMB shares. I am mounting those shares in Linux Mint 20 (via File > Connect To server in Nemo).

Everything works fine (I can create and delete directories and files), but Mint obviously recognises this mounted share is not the local files system, so I am loosing some features (such as the ability to select files from the share when uploading to a browser or drag files from the share into open applications).

I was wondering if there is a way get support for these features? Do I need mount the shares via the command line with custom options? Or maybe do I need to look into using NFS instead?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried mounting the share via the command line (as per: https://linoxide.com/howto-mount-smb-filesystem-using-etcfstab/) and the mount works perfectly (as if it was a local folder). So I can drag files directly into applications etc without issue.

I am guessing Nemo uses a different process to mount the share, but the command is working great for me.